# Behat Errors after Upgrade to 8.5.3

Tags: testing

We are currently upgrading a site from 8.4.8 to 8.5.3. After doing so and running our Behat tests the Behat tests seem to randomly fail on node create with an array_flip error:

```
  Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in /Users/Allison/Sites/devdesktop/secgov-dev/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php line 227 (Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException)
```

Even on different runs the node create will sometimes pass and then sometimes fail with the above error.

Has anyone run into something similar?

Comment: Is this got resolved? solution?

Comment: The `array_flip` error is confusing, and comes from passing a `NULL` value into the entity storage's load method. So my guess is something that should be returning an int ID is now returning NULL. If you run with the `--verbose` flag you should get a stack trace that may reveal more details.

Comment: We figured it out, we have the USA Search Module installed and for whatever reason that needs to be unenabled and then reenabled and it fixed all the issues.